# Strange gem installation runtime depedency error on rake version on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rake

Inside my gemspec file I have:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'rake',
[ '>= 0.9.0.0']
```

On Windows I install it with the command:

```
gem install --local myGem-0.9.0.gem
```

Because --user does not seem to work on windows and it installs in the main ruby gem area.

This works fine the current rake version on that machine is 0.9.2.2 and the current gem version on that machine is 1.8.28

On Ubuntu with the same gemspec file I install it with:

```
gem install --local --user myGem-0.9.0.gem
```

which fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
  Unable to resolve dependencies: myGem requires rake (>= 0.9.0.0)
```

The version of rake installed on that machine is: 10.0.4
and then current gem version on that machine is 1.8.23

I tried changing the gemspec file to '>= 9.0.0' and I got the same error.

This gem uses rake at runtime.
This behavior seems quite contrary to the documentation on the gemspec file.  How do I accomplish this version test? It works fine without a version dependency value.